# "ray through vertex" special case when detecting point in polygon

Tags: geometry, gis, polygon, point

To detect if a point is in a polygon, you project a line from the point, to infinity, and see how many of polygon's vertices it intersects with... simple enough.  My problem is that if the ray intersects the polygon on one of the points, then it is counted as intersecting two segments, and considered outside the polygon.  I altered my function to make it only count one of the segments when the ray intersects a point of the polygon, but there are cases where a line could intersect the point while still being outside as well.  Take this image as an example:

[image: two examples of a ray crossing a polygon vertex]

If you assume the point in the top left is "infinity", and cast a ray to either of the other points, both intersect at a point of the polygon, and would count as intersecting the same number of vertices even though one is inside, and one is outside.

Is there a way to compensate for that, or do I just have to assume that those fringe cases won't pop up?

Comment: though this is somewhat late, a similar problem exists here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4445701/585488

Answer (score 3):

If the ray crosses a side exactly on a vertex, only count that side if the other vertex is above the ray. That will fix your corner case.

For example in the picture you posted, the lower ray crosses two sides of the square at the top-left vertex, but one side is above the ray and the other below, so that contributes 1 and the target point is found to be inside. The upper ray crosses two sides at the top-right vertex, both sides are below the ray, so they contribute 0 to the count and the target point is found to be outside.

**Update**:

I remembered reading an article which describes a technique for dealing with singular cases in general. Please read my other answer if interested.

Comment: What if a ray intersects the lower left corner?

Comment: Then both sides are above, which contributes 2 to the count, which is even, so the point will be considered to be outside the square.

Comment: ah, I see what you are saying.  I will give that a try.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. By the way, one way of simplifying calculations is to use horizontal rays only, it will make your calculations easier and your code faster.

Comment: And by the way, I remembered reading about a general technique for dealing with these kind of issues, http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9410209.pdf. I will update my post with this info.

Answer (score 0):

While my first answer should do the trick for this simple problem, I can't help but mention that there exist general techniques for dealing with these kinds of special cases.

[This article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9410209.pdf) describes a technique for dealing with these kinds of issues in general. And one of the first examples they provide happens to be the algorithm you ask about!

The idea is to apply [Automatic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) aka [Dual numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) to compute symbolic perturbations.

By the way the same technique can also be used to avoid handling 0/0 as a special case in programs!

[Here](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/05/desingularisation-and-its-applications.html) is the blog post I originally learned this from, it gives some great background to the technique, and the author blogs a lot about automatic differentiation (AD).

Despite appearances AD is a very practical technique especially in languages with good support for operator overloading (eg: C++, Haskell, Python ...) and I have used it in "real life" (industrial applications in C++).

Answer (score 0):

Send ray in another direction.

If you try `n+1` different directions (`n` is number of polygon points) one of them surely will not pass through any vertex.

This will simplify the code compared to consideration of corner cases.

Worst case becomes `O(n)*CheckComplexity(n)` which is likely `O(n^2)`. If it's not acceptable, you can just sort all vertices by direction from the point to them and select middle of some interval. This will give `O(n*log n)`.